# Gutenberg block attribute with random value not saving

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I need to have a unique ID for a gutenberg block, but since i didn't find a way do to it easily i choosed to use a random value to get a number that's probably unique (i'd have to be very unlucky to have it generate the same number two times in the same page).

But there's a problem... Every time i save the block it corrupt itself because the ID get recreated everytime, even tough that's just the default value so it should be used only if the block has just been created.

This is my block:

```
registerBlockType('materialize-fcd/gallery-block', {
    title: "Material Gallery - Galleria",
    icon: 'images-alt',
    category: 'common',

    attributes: {
        images: {
            type: 'array',
            default: null
        },
        ids: {
            type: 'array',
            default: null
        },
        size: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'full'
        },

        s: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 6
        },
        m: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 4
        },
        l: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 3
        },
        lightbox:{
            type: 'string',
            default: 'gal_'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000)
        }
    },


    edit(props) {
        const {
            setAttributes,
            attributes,
        } = props;

        function changeS(newValue) {
            setAttributes({
                s: newValue
            })
        }
        function changeM(newValue) {
            setAttributes({
                m: newValue
            })
        }
        function changeL(newValue) {
            setAttributes({
                l: newValue
            })
        }
        function onChangeSize(value) {
            setAttributes({
                size: value
            })
        }
        function onChangeLightbox(value) {
            setAttributes({
                lightbox: value
            })
        }


        function onImagesSelect(imageObject) {
            var id_array = imageObject.map(image => image.id);
            setAttributes({
                images: imageObject,
                ids: id_array
            })
            console.log(attributes.images);
        }


        var choices = [];
        if (attributes.images != null) {
            //ciclo le immagini
            for(var i in attributes.images){
                //ciclo le sizes
                for (var name in attributes.images[i].sizes) {

                    if (!choices.map(choice=>choice.value).includes(name)){
                        var choice = {
                            value: name,
                            label: name
                        }
                        if(name == attributes.size) choice.selected = true;
                        choices.push(choice);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        var mediaButton = (<MediaUpload  onSelect={onImagesSelect} type="image"
                                    value={attributes.ids}
                                    render={ ({ open}) => { return (
                                        <button onClick={open}>
                                            Choose image
                                        </button>);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    multiple = 'add'
                                    />);
        var images = [];
        for (var i in attributes.images) {
            images.push(<img style={{"max-width" : "150px", "max-height" : "150px"}} src={attributes.images[i].sizes.full.url}/>);
        }

        return ([(
                    <InspectorControls>
                        <PanelBody title='Column Size'>
                            <PanelRow>
                                <RangeControl
                                    label="Mobile (S)"
                                    value={ attributes.s }
                                    onChange={changeS}
                                    min={ 0 }
                                    max={ 12 }
                                    />
                            </PanelRow>
                            <PanelRow>
                                <RangeControl
                                    label="Tablets (M)"
                                    value={ attributes.m }
                                    onChange={changeM}
                                    min={ 0 }
                                    max={ 12 }
                                    />
                            </PanelRow>
                            <PanelRow>
                                <RangeControl
                                    label="Desktops (L)"
                                    value={ attributes.l }
                                    onChange={changeL}
                                    min={ 0 }
                                    max={ 12 }
                                    />
                            </PanelRow>
                        </PanelBody>
                        <PanelBody title='Image Size'>
                            <PanelRow>
                                <SelectControl
                                            label='Image size:'
                                            value={attributes.size}
                                            onChange={onChangeSize}
                                            options={choices}
                                            />
                            </PanelRow>
                        </PanelBody>
                        <PanelBody title='Lightbox'>
                            <PanelRow>
                                <TextControl
                                            label='Gallery ID:'
                                            value={attributes.lightbox}
                                            onChange={onChangeLightbox}
                                            />
                            </PanelRow>
                        </PanelBody>
                        <PanelBody title='Images'>
                            <PanelRow>
                                {mediaButton}
                            </PanelRow>
                        </PanelBody>
                    </InspectorControls>
                    ),(
                    <div>

                    {attributes.className ?'CLASS: ' + attributes.className : null}
                    {attributes.className ?<br/> : null}
                    {mediaButton}
                    <br/>
                    {attributes.images != null ? images : ''}
                    </div>
                    )]);
    },

    save(props) {

        const { attributes, className } = props;
        var images = [];
        var cols = (props.attributes.s != 0 ? ' s' + props.attributes.s : '') + (props.attributes.m != 0 ? ' m' + props.attributes.m : '') + (props.attributes.l != 0 ? ' l' + props.attributes.l : '') + (props.attributes.className ? ' '+props.attributes.className : '');

        for (var i in attributes.images) {
            images.push(
                <div class={'col' + cols}>
                    <a sl={(attributes.lightbox == '' || attributes.lightbox == null) ? null : attributes.lightbox} href={attributes.images[i].sizes.full.url} class={(attributes.className ? attributes.className + ' ' : '')+'waves-effect waves-light img gal z-depth-2'}>
                        <img src={attributes.images[i].sizes[attributes.size].url} />
                    </a>
                </div>
            );
        }
        return (
            <div class="row">
                {images}
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

And this is the error i get:

```
Block validation failed
Content generated by `save` function:

<div class="row" class="wp-block-materialize-fcd-gallery-block"><div class="col s6 m4 l3"><a sl="gal_7827" href="https://www.torvaianicahotel.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/IMG-20181206-WA0010.jpg" class="waves-effect waves-light img gal z-depth-2"><img src="https://www.torvaianicahotel.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/IMG-20181206-WA0010.jpg"/></a></div></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div class="row" class="wp-block-materialize-fcd-gallery-block"><div class="col s6 m4 l3"><a sl="gal_2133" href="https://www.torvaianicahotel.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/IMG-20181206-WA0010.jpg" class="waves-effect waves-light img gal z-depth-2"><img src="https://www.torvaianicahotel.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/IMG-20181206-WA0010.jpg"/></a></div></div>
```

The only difference between the two is the different random number, so it seems like the lightbox attribute doesn't get saved and it's reinstantiated to the default value every time... ?
Any idea of why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

Seems like i managed to fix it by setting the default value to null and check on edit if it was null and then set the attribute to the random value if it was null...

I have no idea why this works, so if someone can explain me i'd still be interested in a proper explaination. (That's why i didn't answer myself)

Answer (score 3):

Here's why your block is encountering errors:

Block validation is checked based on the rendered `save` output. When you load the block editor and the re-generated `save` output markup doesn't change, then there's no error.

In your case, since you have an attribute that always gets randomly generated, the rendered `save` output changes every time as well. So every time you run the `save` function, you always get a unique markup, and making the block invalid.

By changing the attribute's default value to `null`, then only generating the unique ID it when it's `null` would prevent future loading from re-generating the value and invalidating the block.

Also, every block has a property called clientId that's already a random unique ID, so it might also be a good idea to use that instead of generating your own.

Answer (score 1):

By the look of it, Gutenberg does not actually save the default attributes as the real attributes when you create the block. Instead, if the attributes didn't change at all(as default), it will get the default attributes again the next time when you refresh the page. That explains why the random string changes every time unless you actually call the setAttributes function to save it.

The workaround I had to use, is to add a `blockInitialized` attribute and set it to false by default. Use 'useEffect' on block first rendering and check if the attribute `blockInitialized` is false, if it is, set it to true and set whatever the attributes that have random strings to be a clone of itself.

This approach only causes one extra re-render on the initial block creation and does not do anything afterward.